# How can I work around Visual C++ 2005's "decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated" warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, warnings, name-decoration

For example, say for some reason I had a piece of code that looked like this:

```
mutable std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<
std::vector<MyNamespace::MyType> > > > > myFreakingLongVectorThing;
```

and I am getting a warning that looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\xstring(1665) : warning   
    C4503: 'std::vector<_Ty>::operator []' : decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated
    with
    [
      _Ty=std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<MyNamespace::MyType>>>>>
    ]
```

is there any way I could rewrite that freaking long vector thing to not get that warning?  I still want the data structure to be the same, but not get that warning.  I don't want to disable the warning. Possible?

Note: This is Visual Studio 2005

....if you're really curious about why I'm working with such a hideous data structure, it's caused by auto-generated code.

Comment: FWIW, Microsoft increased the maximum length of decorated names in VC++ 2008, largely because of Boost library authors complaining about this exact issue. Any chance you can join the modern world and use a compiler that isn't 7 years old? ;-]

Comment: This isn't Visual Studio's fault at all, it's VC++'s fault. I've modified the title and tags accordingly.

Comment: `I still want the data structure to be the same, but not get that warning. I don't want to disable the warning. Possible?` <-- I don't believe so.

Comment: ildjarn: We're working on joining the real world of modern compilers!  So on Visual Studio 2008 this would be ok?

Comment: I added https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15893887-fix-decorated-name-length-exceeded-name-was-trun as this is still a problem in VS2015

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't want to see the warning you either have to disable it or use a newer compiler.

The warning is about debug information being limited to 255 characters for the type name. As long as these 255 characters are not *identical* for two different types, you are ok. And if they are identical, you cannot do much about it anyway!

Just turn it off until you can upgrade the compiler!

Comment: I'm getting this problem with VS 2010. :(

Comment: Getting it with VS 2012 :(.  I guess this isn't a priority to them.

Comment: Continues to be an issue with VS2013 Nov CTP :-(

Comment: they increased it to 4096 but its still causing problems with meta programming where you can build type lists from type lists. they should simply use variable lengths strings, why the hell do they use these kinds of limitations ? there is a rule, its known as "zero, one, infinite". they don't respect it.

Comment: believe it or not, but this warning even from VS2015 has brought me here :<

Comment: @dahnoak I can confirm... I also encountered it in VS2015 (while it seemingly does not appear with VS2012 in my case).

Comment: Same here, with VS2015; but for me it's not a warning, it's an ERROR. And it's blocking the build. [C4503](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=IT-IT&k=k(C4503)&rd=true). And I still have no idea how to avoid this error.

Comment: Still problem in VS2015. `std::function` inside namespace is almost guaranteed to result in this warning, and if you have turned all warnings to error this is a build stopper.

Comment: @ocramot I believe you've used -WX compiler option (treat all compiler warnings as errors). I get the same result (error from the topic) with variadic templates. From both MSVC 2015.3 and ICL 16.3 under Windows :-(

Comment: Same sh.. problem in VS2017 :(

Comment: boost guys recommend to suppress C4503:
https://svn.boost.org/trac10/wiki/Guidelines/WarningsGuidelines#SpecificWarningsandSuggestedActions.

Comment: VS2019 still the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't all that different from the error I used to get in Visual C++ 6 anytime I did just about anything with STL maps. You simply need to bite the bullet and tell the compiler to shut up about that warning. It's got a fundamental internal limit on how long a type name can be. As it is, it's a pretty useless warning, just complaining about the compiler/debugger's internal name limit.

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4503)
```

And if you're thinking at all about porting to another compiler, just wrap it in a #ifdef for Visaul C++:

```
#ifdef MSVC
  #pragma warning(disable : 4503)
#endif
```

Comment: Better to use #ifdef _MSC_VER as this is actually a predefined macro that VC uses whereas MSVC isn't predefined. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx